# Show $\frac{1}{n}$ converges to $0$ using topological definition

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

I need to use the following definition to show that:

$\frac{1}{n}$ converge to $0$ in $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_{usual})$ and $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_{lowerlimit})$

The defnition is:

> Given $(X, \mathcal{T})$, $x_n \in X$ a sequence, $x_n \to x$ if $\forall U \in \mathcal{T}$, $x \in U$, there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $x_n \in U, \forall
>  n \geq N$

I am having trouble producing the $N$

1. Show  $\frac{1}{n}$ converge to $0$ in $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_{usual})$

Let $0 \in U, U \in \mathcal{T}_{usual}$. Since $\forall x \in U, \exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $B_\delta(x) \subseteq U$, therefore $0 \in B_\delta(0) \subseteq U$. Then let $x_N = \frac{1}{N} = \frac{\delta}{2} \implies N = \frac{2}{\delta}$, hence $x_n \in U, \forall n \geq N$

**Here, I have no guarantee that $N \in \mathbb{N}$!!**

1. Show  $\frac{1}{n}$ converge to $0$ in $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_{lowerlimit})$

Let $0 \in U, U \in \mathcal{T}_{lowerlimit}$. Since $U = \bigcup\{[a,b)|a<b\}$, therefore there exists some $[a,b)$ such that $0 \in [a,b)$. Then let $x_N = \frac{1}{N} = \frac{|b-a|}{2} \implies N = \frac{2}{|b-a|}$, hence $x_n \in U, \forall n \geq N$

**Again, no guarantee that $N \in \mathbb{N}$**

How to fix these cases?

Comment: Take the ceiling

Comment: Say, $N\ge \frac 2{\delta}$ instead of equal to.  Then you can choose the samallest $N \in \mathbb N$ that meets the criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a natural number $N_0$ *larger* than the candidate real $N$. Larger $n$ only makes $\frac{1}{n}$ smaller anyway.

For the second one, it suffices to consider neighbourhoods of the form $[0,a)$, even (why?).

Answer (score 2):

In $X$=$(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T}_{usual})$:

Define $B_{r}(x)$ as the open ball with radius $r$ centered at $x$$\in$$X$.

We note that $B_{2}(0)$ contains ${(1/n)}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Let $U\in\mathcal{T}_{usual}$ be a proper open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $0$. Then there exists some open ball $B=B_{\epsilon}(0)$, $\epsilon>0$, such that $B\subseteq U$.

Hence, for all $n\geq N>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, $x_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$$\in$$B$, and we are done.

For $X=(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T}_{lowerlimit})$,the basis of the topology of $X$ has elements of the form $[x,y)$, so repeat as in the first case but observe that $1/n>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.